# access script variable in js file from phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

i defined variable in phtml file under script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = 'hello World';
</script>
```

I created one Js file test.js under skin js folder now i want to access that variable value in js file how to do it

Comment: Just make sure page is loaded before running your JS code ... it should be available there.

Comment: yes js is loading but its not working

Comment: What is the content of your test.js file ?

Comment: How are you loading test.js?  Please try loading it like `<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/path/to/test.js'); ?>"></script>` below where you define the variable.